# Centos. infiniband multicast join failed for status -22

Tags: linux, centos, multicast, infiniband

I have a cluster with Linux Centos 6.5 as OS.
All the machines are connected by infiniband, the network is working fine but in the /var/log/messages of all the machines I can see the following message

ib0: multicast join failed for ff12:401b:ffff:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001, status -22

However, if I execute a check, I obtain the following:

```
#ibcheckstate
Summary: 56 nodes checked, 0 bad nodes found
      176 ports checked, 0 ports with bad state found
```

Thanks and regards

Comment: Could you post the SM configuration?

Comment: Could you also post any relevant info about the OFED/IB software stack being used?  Did you build and compile OFED locally or use parts that were included with the OS?  Is there a managed/"intelligent" IB switch anywhere in the mix?